# Plotting large datasets with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I convert an oscilloscope dataset with millions of values into a pandas DataFrame. Next step is to plot it. But Matplotlib needs on my fairly powerful machine ~50 seconds to plot the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc    

datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc')

srx, sry = pd.Series(datX), pd.Series(datY)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

df.plot(grid = 1)
plt.show()
```

Now I found out that there is a way to make matplotlib faster with large datasets by using 'Agg'.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc

datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc')

srx, sry = pd.Series(datX), pd.Series(datY)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

df.plot(grid = 1)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately no plot is shown. The process of processing the plot takes ~5 seconds (a big improvement) but no plot is shown. Is this method not compatible with pandas?

Comment: The reason the second code is faster is precisely that no plot is produced (`Agg` does not produce any screen output.). This way you found out that processing the data takes ~10% of the time, while plotting it takes 90%.

Comment: So matplotlib is the wrong library for this task?

Comment: No, I would say the expectation to draw millions of points fast on the screen is not compatible with what plots are usually used for. As said, use less points.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ploty](https://plotly.com/python/) and [Lenspy](https://github.com/serant/lenspy) (was built to solve this exact problem). Here is an example of how you can plot 10m points on scatter plot. This plot runs super fast on my 2016 MacBook.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from lenspy import DynamicPlot

# First, let's create a very large figure
x = np.arange(1, 11, 1e-6)
y = 1e-2*np.sin(1e3*x) + np.sin(x) + 1e-3*np.sin(1e10*x)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scattergl(x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_layout(title=f"{len(x):,} Data Points.")

# Use DynamicPlot.show to view the plot
plot = DynamicPlot(fig)
plot.show()

# Plot will be available in the browser at http://127.0.0.1:8050/
```

For your use case (again, I cannot test this since I don’t have access to your dataset):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc   
from lenspy import DynamicPlot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc')

srx, sry = pd.Series(datX), pd.Series(datY)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scattergl(x=srx, y=sry)])
fig.update_layout(title=f"{len(x):,} Data Points.")

# Use DynamicPlot.show to view the plot
plot = DynamicPlot(fig)
plot.show()
```

Disclaimer: I am the creator of Lenspy